# Angular 7 location.back without reloading the page

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular7

I am using angular 7, and I have a list of items when I click on one item it's go to edit the item page,I put a back button in edit item page, when I click back it's reload the items page and go to the top of the page,
How can I go back without reload the page or return back to the last position in the list.

that's what was trying:

```
<button type="button" (click)="onBack()" style="width:49%" class="btn btn-secondary btn-lg">cancel</button>

onBack() {
    console.log("on back...");
   
    this.location.back();
    return false
}
```

Comment: https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/angular-route-reuse-strategy-b5d40adce841#:%7E:text=When%20navigating%20away%20from%20a,user%2F57%20for%20example read this

Answer (score 0):

Try `this.router.navigate(['---Name of your route---']);`

Comment: router does not exist

Comment: than how do you reach that page with list of items?

Comment: I import router, but the same problem still, when click back the page is reload

Comment: this.router.navigate(['products/list']);

Comment: this.router.navigate(['products','list']);

Comment: strange, and when you add routerLink to your button `<button type="button" [routerLink]="['/products/list']"` would it reload the page?